# Asset catalog in blue folder reference?

Tags: xcode, xcasset

Can I have a number of automatically generated asset catalogs in a "blue" folder? If so, how do I access them?

**Edit:**
By blue folder, I mean a folder ref instead of the yellow group. This folder than expects number of xcassets folders that may change everytime developer builds the project.

Comment: Hi @Ondrej... Can you be more specific that what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "number of automatically generated asset catalogs"??? Do you want number of catalog that are in xcasset folder programmatically??

Comment: with the generated catalogs I mean that wanted to generate them outside of xcode (or in a build phase) ... thus explaining why I need the blue folder ... because I never know what will be inside up front ... I jus added more info

Comment: Why would you like to generate them outside of Xcode?? What is your end goal by doing this. What is the advantage of doing such thing?

Comment: That is a bit outside of the question isn't it :) ... because we have made some really cool stuff that we will share with the dev community in a couple of months and this would make it even more awesome :)